# npm activedirectory get objectGUID

Tags: node.js, npm, ldap

I have a Nodejs application and I can't seem to get an entities unique ID's
here is the module I am using:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory

pulling for groups and I can't seem to get the following attributes:

- objectGUID
- objectSid

here is the snippet

```
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(domainConfig);
var query = 'CN=*';
ad.findGroups(query, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        log.error("No Groups found.");
    }
    log.info(result);
});
```

am I missing something?
by default, all attributes should be returning

> attributes - attributes to select and return (if these are set, the
>   server will return only these attributes). Defaults to the empty set,
>   which means all attributes.

Comment: Have you solved the problem with rubbish instead of data? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46810881/4928642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, this is an error. However, you can get around this by explicitly specifying the attributes that you want. Note that these are case sensitive.

```
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(domainConfig);
var query = { filter: 'CN=*'
              attributes: ["dn", "cn", "description", "objectGUID", "objectSid"]};
ad.findGroups(query, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        log.error("No Groups found.");
    }
    log.info(result);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting rubbish instead of the data: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46810881/4928642