# Convert objectGuid to UUID string using Javascript

Tags: active-directory, ping, uuid, ldapjs

I have been looking for a way to convert the ObjectGuid out of Active Directory is a special type that gets converted to a string, which is odd looking, using libraries such as ldapjs and or adding it as a claim using ping federate. An example of this is the following:

```
const ldapjs = require("ldapjs");
let _client = ldapjs.createClient({
        "url": this._ldap_uri
      });
_client.search(this._search_dn, opts, (error, res) => {
          res.on("searchEntry", (entry) => {
              console.log(entry.object.objectGUID)
          }
```

Here is an example of the output that comes out of ldapjs. The same comes out of a ping federate when you add it as a claim.

```
H�Y��fB�_-_���
```

However, this is equivalent to a valid UUID.

```
b9****48-6***-42**-a**f-2d5f*****40b
```

What I am trying to do is convert this strange value to a the correct UUID. I have scoured and tested a few different postings and websites but I have not found a valid solution.

Here are a few I researched:

- [Read objectGUID from active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810881/read-objectguid-from-active-directory)
- [Javascript convert GUID in string format into Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095115/javascript-convert-guid-in-string-format-into-base64)
- http://www.tdi-users.org/foswiki/Integrator/UsingGUIDs

If anyone has a solution to this it would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to get the value you're seeing? Did you try the code in the answer to the [Read objectGUID from active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810881/read-objectguid-from-active-directory) question?

Comment: @GabrielLuci - This comes straight out of PING federate as a JWT claim and the client library ldapjs library in this format so there is not much to show. However, I will add more information if it would be helpful

Comment: I ended up working with the PING federate administrator and they were able to convert it to Hex encoded format, which allowed me to convert it to a UUID. This solves the immediate problem but it would be nice to have an solution to the conversion problem

Comment: That "strange value" just looks like a byte array. Did you try the code in [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46812034/1202807)? Particularly the `.toString('hex').replace( ... )`. If that doesn't work, I think the question you really need the answer to is how do you convert a GUID byte array to a string.

Answer (score 0):

experiment with this code (read GUID) :

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function( len, str ) {
        //return Array( len - String(this).length + 1 ).join(str) + this;
        var s = this;
        str = str || '0';
        if ( str.length > 0 ) {
            while ( s.length < len ) {
                s = ( str + s );
            };
        }
        return s;
    }

var destAD = GetObject("LDAP://dc.yourdomain.pl/cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=yourdomain,dc=pl");
var guidValueArr = destAD.Get("objectguid").toArray();
var guid = "", i;
for ( i = 0; i < guidValueArr.length; i ++ ) {
    guid += guidValueArr[i].toString(16).padLeft(2,"0");
}
var guidFormated = guid.replace(/(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{4})(.{12})/, "$4$3$2$1-$6$5-$8$7-$9-$10");
alert( guidFormated );
```

[Universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)